# What is the best way to update subviews when some events happen on the parent view With Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a parent view that has two or more subviews, I am wondering how can I let the subviews know some events had occurred in the parent view, so that they can fetch the data and then render?

Currently, I use the custom event to do that. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a problem using a custom event. If they share models or collections, you could subscribe to the events that are changing the parent view.

Comment: This is exactly what custom events are for. What issues are you facing  that have prompted you to request an alternative?

Comment: yep, custom events is better suitable for this situation, I just wonder is there some other solutions for that. :)